# TypeError: points[(pointsLength - 1)] is undefined while using multicolor_series.js

Tags: highcharts

I am facing a problem that Series of Lines in the Chart is not getting plotted unless one series (Previous Year)is disabled on the chart output.

In the New Chart Loaded image you can see the loaded chart. Now when I disable a series the other series is plotted see the image in the link below,

I noticed when the problem occurs I see  an error "TypeError: points[(pointsLength - 1)] is undefined" while using multicolor_series.js in the console log.

I have attached my "ecmhtb.php" the chart rendering file and "ed.php" where the data is prepared to convert it as JSON. Also I have attached the Data Table which is used to fetch the data from SQL and also the processed out of SQL Data for JSON conversion as excel files.

The above mentioned issue comes in few set of data and other are working as expected. I have updated all the required files in google drive for inspection the link to the files [Click-here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B7s2Ef_izL9EN0gtd0JoNVVhMmM?usp=sharing)

I kindly request to help me in solving the issue.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  To help other's help you, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Related [github report](https://github.com/blacklabel/multicolor_series/issues/25).

Comment: Please find the js fiddle [link]http://jsfiddle.net/mailsakthi/zL81e30z/1/ attached for your perusal. Once you load the page the Plan line will not be visible and then once you click on Previous year the Plan line will pop up. Let me know if I can be of any further information.

Comment: After the latest commit on the repo: https://github.com/blacklabel/multicolor_series the problem is fixed. Take a look at this corrected demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5mssLvmu/.

Comment: Thank you very much, the issue is fixed with the new version.